# Regular expression with mod_rewrite: ".../auto/bmw?year=2014&..." to ".../auto.php?company=bmw?year=2014&..."

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have links like this(with unknown number of variables) that I want to change:

> ```
> http://test.my/news/auto?year=2014&thema2=design
> http://test.my/news/auto?year=2005&...
> http://test.my/news/moto?year=2012&month=10&championship=MotoGP
> ```

Into like this:

> ```
> http://test.my/news.php?thema=moto&year=2012&month=10&&championship=MotoGP
> http://test.my/news.php?thema=auto&year=2014&thema2=design
> ```

I tried to do so, but failed:

```
RewriteRule ^news/([a-zA-Z_.]+)\??([a-zA-Z0-9_-.]+)$ news.php?thema=$1&$2 [NC,L,QSA]
```

php vardump($_GET):

```
array(6) { 
["thema"]=> string(5) "mot" 
["o"]=> string(0) ""
["year"]=> string(4) "2012" 
["month"]=> string(2) "10"
["championship"]=> string(6) "MotoGP" }
```

I think there is a problem with a question mark and with a second part of regexp.
Please tell me how do this better. Thanks.

Comment: You don't have to get the query part in your rewrite. As long as you use `[QSA]` the params will be transferred automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this rule in your root `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteRule ^(news)/([\w-]+)/?$ $1.php?thema=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Sorry for my fault. I have edited the question. (result must be "my server.com/news.php?class=auto&company=...")

Comment: Last change please. (I was in a hurry) /news/moto?year=2012& <- question mark between moto and year. "news" = news.php them = moto yaar= ... etc

Comment: Is `moto` fixed word or can change? Also you are not using `auto` in target URI

Comment: "news" that is script name. "auto", "moto", "plane" etc that thema's names(script "name" parameter) and can change.